# PHP library to output image charts server-side?

Tags: php, charts, server-side

I need to generate some charts server-side. I'm gonna need column charts and pie charts for now. They are going to be integrated into PDF reports. I've looked into some libraries I've used before (pCharts and others), but it seems they are all abandoned for the last few years.

What do you use for server-side image rendering? I need a solution that outputs images in pure PHP server-side, no JS printing and no headless browsers.

There were ton of those before and now I can't find any project that is still alive.

Any ideas?

Comment: for charts i will strongly recommend:- [Highcharts library](https://www.highcharts.com/demo)

Comment: Highcharts are too expensive for my customer.

Comment: it's free of cast

Comment: It's not free for commercial projects: https://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts/ And it looks like it is a JS client side chart...

Comment: i used this library free for multiple websites(commercial) without any issue. Now it depends on your website what and how much it needed from the library so that there is a need of purchase.

Comment: For chart images to include into PDF you might want to give a try to https://image-charts.com

Comment: This is interesting concept, but I'd prefer to generate images on my own server.